# PHP: echo is not working

Tags: php, echo, output

```
<?php
$val1 = echo "".$response['players'].""; // it will output 1
$val2 = echo "".$response['maxplayers'].""; // it will output 3

$res = ($val1 / $val2) * 100;

echo $res; // it will output 33,33333
?
```

**but this error comes up:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) 
in /home/mcthebli/public_html/test.php on line 36
```

Someone know what im going wrong? :/

Comment: This is on line 36. WHat's before it? You're probably missing a semi-colon or something.

Comment: Oh wait I'm retarded. Maybe I should read the code, instead of the error. Nevermind me.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` does not return a value.

try this,

```
$val1 = $response['players']; 
$val2 = $response['maxplayers'];
$res = ($val1 / $val2) * 100;

echo '(' . $val1 . '/' . $val2 . ') * 100 = ' . $res;
```

let's say `$val1 = 5` and `$val2 = 5`, it will output

```
(5 / 5) * 100 = 100
```

Comment: Hehehe 
this was the new code 

    <?php
    $val1 = $response['players']; echo $val1; 
    $val2 = $response['maxplayers']; echo $val2; 
    
    $res = ($val1 / $val2) * 100;
    
    echo $res; 
    ?>
answer is wrong (212000.166666666667)
@491243

Comment: i don't think so. you need to round the result, *I guess*.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is for output. Don't use it if you're just assigning a value to a variable.

```
$foo = 'bar';
```